is this a issue happening when switching from file to file or from file to main file? in the lexer?
I have created a simple interpreter using C, Flex (for the lexer), and Bison (for the parser). The interpreter supports variables, arrays, and 2-dimensional arrays. Additionally, I have implemented a feature to include files inside the main file that will be executed by the interpreter. My goal is to allow users to create libraries and for me, as the creator of the language, to develop a standard library.
However, I am encountering an issue: I receive a "Parse error: syntax error" for each file I include. If I add more files, multiple "Parse error: syntax error" messages appear after the interpreter finishes executing my code. If I do not include any files, I do not receive these errors.
My code consists of the following files:

main.c
parser.y
lexer.l
hashtable.c
hashtable.h
garbagecollection.c
garbagecollection.h
for testing the program
test.hussein
filen.hslib
filto.hslib

main.c:
#include "parser.tab.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
extern FILE *yyin;

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
HINSTANCE hInstance;
#endif

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
#ifdef _WIN32
    hInstance = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
#endif
  
    initialize_hashtable();
    initialize_garbage_collection();

    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <filename.hussein>\n", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    // Ensure that the file has a .hussein extension
    const char *filename = argv[1];
    const char *extension = strrchr(filename, '.');
    if (!extension || strcmp(extension, ".hussein") != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Only .hussein files are accepted as input\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!file) {
        perror("Error opening file");
        return 1;
    }

    yyin = file;

    yyparse();

    fclose(file);
    //garbage_collect();
    
    return 0;
}


parser.y:
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "hashtable.h"
#include "garbagecollection.h"

int array_size;
int twod_array_size_row;
int twod_array_size_col;

#define YYDEBUG 1
extern int yydebug;
%}

%union {
   int num;
   char *str;
}

%token <str> EQUALS
%token <str> SEMICOLON
%token <str> PLUS
%token <str> MINUS
%token <str> MULTIPLY
%token <str> DIVIDE
%token LPAR
%token RPAR
%token <str> LCB
%token <str> RCB
%token <str> MAIN
%token <str> LIBDEF
%token FREEMEM
%token <str> CALL
%token VAR
%token FILENAME

%token <num> NUMBER
%token <str> IDENT
%token <str> LSB
%token <str> RSB
%token <str> COMMA
%token IMPORT

%type <num> expr
%type <str> var_declaration assignment display
%type <str> statement_list
%type <str> libprogstart

%left PLUS MINUS
%left MULTIPLY DIVIDE

%start program

%%

program: start_stmt 
       ;

start_stmt: libprogstart mainprog
          | mainprog
          ;

libprogstart: LIBDEF LCB statement_list RCB SEMICOLON;

mainprog: import_list_opt MAIN LCB statement_list RCB SEMICOLON
        ;

import_list_opt: import_list
               | /* empty */
               ;
               
import_list: IMPORT_stmt_list
           ;

IMPORT_stmt_list: IMPORT_stmt
                | IMPORT_stmt_list IMPORT_stmt
                ;
IMPORT_stmt: IMPORT FILENAME ;

statement_list: /* empty */
              | statement_list statement SEMICOLON
              ;

statement: var_declaration
         | assignment
         | display
         | freememory
         ;

var_declaration: IDENT LSB expr RSB { insert_array($1,$3); array_size = $3; }
               | VAR IDENT { insert_variable($2); }
               | IDENT LSB expr RSB LSB expr RSB { insert_2d_array($1, $3, $6); twod_array_size_col = $6; twod_array_size_row = $3; }
               ;

assignment: IDENT EQUALS expr %prec EQUALS { update_variable($1, $3); }
          | IDENT LSB expr RSB EQUALS expr %prec EQUALS { update_array_element($1, $3, $6, array_size); }
          | IDENT LSB expr RSB LSB expr RSB EQUALS expr %prec EQUALS { update_2d_array_element($1, $3, $6, $9, twod_array_size_row, twod_array_size_col); }
          ;

display: CALL IDENT %prec CALL { display_variable($2); }
       | CALL IDENT LSB expr RSB %prec CALL { display_array_element($2, $4, array_size); }
       | CALL IDENT LSB expr RSB LSB expr RSB %prec CALL { display_2d_array_element($2, $4, $7, twod_array_size_row, twod_array_size_col); }
       ;

freememory: FREEMEM LPAR IDENT RPAR {
    void *ptr = get_memory_block_pointer($3);
    if(ptr){
        remove_from_garbage_collection(ptr);
    }
    else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Variable '%s' not found\n", $3);
    }
}             

expr: NUMBER { $$ = $1; }
   | IDENT { $$ = get_variable_value($1); }
   | IDENT LSB expr RSB { $$ = get_array_element_value($1, $3, array_size); }
   | IDENT LSB expr RSB LSB expr RSB { $$ = get_2d_array_element_value($1, $3, $6, twod_array_size_row, twod_array_size_col); }
   | expr PLUS expr { $$ = $1 + $3; }
   | expr MINUS expr { $$ = $1 - $3; }
   | expr MULTIPLY expr { $$ = $1 * $3; }
   | expr DIVIDE expr {
       if ($3 != 0) {
           $$ = $1 / $3;
       } else {
           fprintf(stderr, "Error: Division by zero\n");
           $$ = 0;
       }
   }
   | LPAR expr RPAR { $$ = $2; }
   ;

%%

void yyerror(const char *s) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Parse error: %s\n", s);
}


lexer.l:
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "parser.tab.h"
char* yytext;

#define MAX_INCLUDE_DEPTH 100

static FILE* file_stack[MAX_INCLUDE_DEPTH];
static int file_stack_top = -1;

void handle_include(const char* filename) {
    const char *ext = strrchr(filename, '.');
    if (!ext || strcmp(ext, ".hslib") != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Invalid file extension for %s. Only .hslib files are allowed.\n", filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    FILE* file = fopen(filename, "r");
    if (!file) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening library file %s\n", filename);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    if (file_stack_top >= MAX_INCLUDE_DEPTH - 1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Maximum include depth exceeded\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    file_stack[++file_stack_top] = file;
    yypush_buffer_state(yy_create_buffer(file, YY_BUF_SIZE));
    printf("opening file %s\n", filename);
}

void finish_include() {
    if (file_stack_top >= 0) {
        fclose(file_stack[file_stack_top]);
        file_stack[file_stack_top] = NULL;
        file_stack_top--;
        yypop_buffer_state();
        if (file_stack_top < 0) {
            printf("closing library file\n");
        }
    }
}

void print_debug(const char *msg) {
    printf("DEBUG: %s\n", msg);
}
%}

DIGIT      [0-9]
WS         [ \t\n]
IDENT      [a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*


%option stack
%x INCL

%%

"Import" {
  
    BEGIN(INCL); return IMPORT;
}

<INCL>[ \t]*\"[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.hslib\" {
    char filename[256];
    sscanf(yytext, " \"%[^\"]\"", filename);
    handle_include(filename);
    BEGIN(0);
    yyparse();
    return FILENAME;
}

<INCL><<EOF>> {
    if (file_stack_top >= 0) {
        
        finish_include();
    }
    BEGIN(0);
    return 0;
}


{WS}        /* Ignore whitespace */
{DIGIT}+    { yylval.num = atoi(yytext);  return NUMBER; }
"Var"       { return VAR; }
"Void Main()" {  return MAIN; }
"Call"      {  return CALL; }
"Library"   { return LIBDEF; }
"Free"      {  return FREEMEM; }
{IDENT}     { yylval.str = strdup(yytext);  return IDENT; }
"+"         {  return PLUS; }
"-"         { return MINUS; }
"*"         {  return MULTIPLY; }
"/"         {  return DIVIDE; }
"="         {  return EQUALS; }
";"         {  return SEMICOLON; }
"("         {  return LPAR; }
")"         {  return RPAR; }
"{"         {  return LCB; }
"}"         {  return RCB; }
"["         { return LSB; }
"]"         {  return RSB; }
"##".*      { /* ignore comments */ }
"/#"[^#]*"#/" { print_debug("Block comment detected"); /* ignore block comments */ }
.           { fprintf(stderr, "Error: Unexpected character '%s'\n", yytext); }


%%

int yywrap() {
    if (file_stack_top >= 0) {
       
        finish_include();
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

hashtable.c:
#include "hashtable.h"
#include "garbagecollection.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define HASH_SIZE 101

struct Node *hash_table[HASH_SIZE];  // Define hash_table

unsigned int hash(const char *str) {
    unsigned int hash_val = 0;
    while (*str) {
        hash_val = (hash_val << 5) + *str++;
    }
    return hash_val % HASH_SIZE;
}

void initialize_hashtable() {
    for (int i = 0; i < HASH_SIZE; ++i) {
        hash_table[i] = NULL;
    }
}

void insert_variable(const char *name) {
    unsigned int index = hash(name);

    struct Node *new_node = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (!new_node) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Failed to allocate memory for variable node\n");
        return;
    }
    new_node->name = strdup(name);
    if (!new_node->name) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Failed to allocate memory for variable name\n");
        free(new_node);
        return;
    }
    new_node->is_array = 0;
    new_node->value = malloc(sizeof(int));  // Allocate space for single int
    if (!new_node->value) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Failed to allocate memory for variable value\n");
        free(new_node->name);
        free(new_node);
        return;
    }
    *((int *)new_node->value) = 0;  // Default value
    new_node->next = hash_table[index];
    hash_table[index] = new_node;
}

void insert_array(const char *name, int array_size) {
    unsigned int index = hash(name);

    struct Node *new_node = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (!new_node) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Failed to allocate memory for array node\n");
        return;
    }
    new_node->name = strdup(name);
    if (!new_node->name) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Failed to allocate memory for array name\n");
        free(new_node);
        return;
    }
    new_node->is_array = 1;
    new_node->size = array_size;
    new_node->value = malloc(array_size * sizeof(int));  // Allocate space for the array
    if (!new_node->value) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Failed to allocate memory for array value\n");
        free(new_node->name);
        free(new_node);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < array_size; ++i) {
        ((int *)new_node->value)[i] = 0;  // Default values for the array
    }
    new_node->next = hash_table[index];
    hash_table[index] = new_node;
}

void insert_2d_array(const char *name, int rows, int cols) {
    unsigned int index = hash(name);

    struct Node *new_node = (struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
    if (!new_node) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Failed to allocate memory for 2D array node\n");
        return;
    }
    new_node->name = strdup(name);
    if (!new_node->name) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Failed to allocate memory for 2D array name\n");
        free(new_node);
        return;
    }
    new_node->is_array = 1;
    new_node->rows = rows;
    new_node->cols = cols;
    new_node->size = rows * cols;
    new_node->value = malloc(rows * sizeof(int *)); // Allocate space for rows
    if (!new_node->value) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: Failed to allocate memory for 2D array value\n");
        free(new_node->name);
        free(new_node);
        return;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; ++i) {
        ((int **)new_node->value)[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof(int)); // Allocate space for columns
        if (!((int **)new_node->value)[i]) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: Failed to allocate memory for 2D array column\n");
            // Free previously allocated memory
            for (int j = 0; j < i; ++j) {
                free(((int **)new_node->value)[j]);
            }
            free(new_node->name);
            free(new_node->value);
            free(new_node);
            return;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; ++j) {
            ((int **)new_node->value)[i][j] = 0;  // Default values for the 2D array
        }
    }
    new_node->next = hash_table[index];
    hash_table[index] = new_node;
}

void update_variable(const char *name, int value) {
    unsigned int index = hash(name);

    struct Node *current = hash_table[index];
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->name, name) == 0 && !current->is_array) {
            *((int *)current->value) = value;
            // Track allocated memory in garbage collection
            add_to_garbage_collection(current->value);
           // printf("Updated variable %s to %d, added to garbage collection\n", name, value); // Debug print
            return;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Variable '%s' not declared\n", name);
}

void update_array_element(const char *name, int index, int value, int array_size) {
    unsigned int array_index = hash(name);

    struct Node *current = hash_table[array_index];
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->name, name) == 0 && current->is_array) {
            if (index >= 0 && index < current->size) {
                ((int *)current->value)[index] = value;
                // Track allocated memory in garbage collection
                add_to_garbage_collection(&((int *)current->value)[index]);
               // printf("Updated array %s[%d] to %d, added to garbage collection\n", name, index, value); // Debug print
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Array index out of bounds\n");
            }
            return;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Variable '%s' not declared or is not an array\n", name);
}

void update_2d_array_element(const char *name, int row, int col, int value, int rows, int cols) {
    unsigned int array_index = hash(name);

    struct Node *current = hash_table[array_index];
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->name, name) == 0 && current->is_array) {
            if (row >= 0 && row < current->rows && col >= 0 && col < current->cols) {
                ((int **)current->value)[row][col] = value;
                // Track allocated memory in garbage collection
                add_to_garbage_collection(&((int **)current->value)[row][col]);
              //  printf("Updated 2D array %s[%d][%d] to %d, added to garbage collection\n", name, row, col, value); // Debug print
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: 2D Array index out of bounds\n");
            }
            return;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Variable '%s' not declared or is not a 2D array\n", name);
}

int get_variable_value(const char *name) {
    unsigned int index = hash(name);

    struct Node *current = hash_table[index];
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->name, name) == 0 && !current->is_array) {
            return *((int *)current->value);
        }
        current = current->next;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Variable '%s' not declared\n", name);
    return 0;  // Return a default value
}

int get_array_element_value(const char *name, int index, int array_size) {
    unsigned int array_index = hash(name);

    struct Node *current = hash_table[array_index];
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->name, name) == 0 && current->is_array) {
            if (index >= 0 && index < current->size) {
                return ((int *)current->value)[index];
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Array index out of bounds\n");
                return 0;  // Return a default value
            }
        }
        current = current->next;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Variable '%s' not declared or is not an array\n", name);
    return 0;  // Return a default value
}

int get_2d_array_element_value(const char *name, int row, int col, int rows, int cols) {
    unsigned int array_index = hash(name);

    struct Node *current = hash_table[array_index];
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->name, name) == 0 && current->is_array) {
            if (row >= 0 && row < current->rows && col >= 0 && col < current->cols) {
                return ((int **)current->value)[row][col];
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: 2D Array index out of bounds\n");
                return 0;  // Return a default value
            }
        }
        current = current->next;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Variable '%s' not declared or is not a 2D array\n", name);
    return 0;  // Return a default value
}

void display_variable(const char *name) {
    unsigned int index = hash(name);

    struct Node *current = hash_table[index];
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->name, name) == 0 && !current->is_array) {
            printf("%s = %d\n", name, *((int *)current->value));
            return;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Variable '%s' not declared\n", name);
}

void display_array_element(const char *name, int index, int array_size) {
    unsigned int array_index = hash(name);

    struct Node *current = hash_table[array_index];
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->name, name) == 0 && current->is_array) {
            if (index >= 0 && index < current->size) {
                printf("%s[%d] = %d\n", name, index, ((int *)current->value)[index]);
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: Array index out of bounds\n");
            }
            return;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }

    fprintf(stderr, "Error: Variable '%s' not declared or is not an array\n", name);
}

void display_2d_array_element(const char *name, int row, int col, int rows, int cols) {
    unsigned int array_index = hash(name);

    struct Node *current = hash_table[array_index];
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->name, name) == 0 && current->is_array) {
            if (row >= 0 && row < current->rows && col >= 0 && col < current->cols) {
                printf("%s[%d][%d] = %d\n", name, row, col, ((int **)current->value)[row][col]);
            } else {
                fprintf(stderr, "Error: 2D Array index out of bounds\n");
            }
            return;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }

  
}


hashtable.h:
// hashtable.h

#ifndef HASHTABLE_H
#define HASHTABLE_H

#define HASH_SIZE 101

struct Node {
    char *name;
    int is_array;  // Indicates whether the variable is an array
    void *value;   // Value can be int or int array
    int size;      // Size of the array
    int rows;
    int cols;
    struct Node *next;
};

extern struct Node *hash_table[HASH_SIZE];  // Declare hash_table as external

unsigned int hash(const char *str); // Ensure the hash function is declared



void initialize_hashtable();
void insert_variable(const char *name);
void insert_array(const char *name, int array_size);
void insert_2d_array(const char *name, int rows, int cols);
void update_variable(const char *name, int value);
void update_array_element(const char *name, int index, int value, int array_size);
void update_2d_array_element(const char *name, int row, int col, int value,int rows ,int cols);
int get_variable_value(const char *name);
int get_array_element_value(const char *name, int index, int array_size);
int get_2d_array_element_value(const char *name, int row, int col,int rows,int cols);
void display_variable(const char *name);
void display_array_element(const char *name, int index, int array_size);
void display_2d_array_element(const char *name, int row, int col,int rows,int cols);

#endif  // HASHTABLE_H


garbagecollection.c:
#include "garbagecollection.h"
#include "hashtable.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Definition for the garbage collection linked list
static struct MemoryBlock *garbage_collection = NULL;

// Function to initialize garbage collection
void initialize_garbage_collection() {
    garbage_collection = NULL;
}

// Function to add a memory block to the garbage collection list
void add_to_garbage_collection(void *ptr) {
    // Check if the block is already in the garbage collection list
    struct MemoryBlock *current = garbage_collection;
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (current->ptr == ptr) {
           // printf("Memory block %p is already in the garbage collection\n", ptr); // Debug print
            return; // Already in the list, do not add again
        }
        current = current->next;
    }

    // If not found, add to the list
    struct MemoryBlock *block = (struct MemoryBlock *)malloc(sizeof(struct MemoryBlock));
    if (!block) {
       // fprintf(stderr, "Error: Failed to allocate memory for garbage collection\n");
        return;
    }
    block->ptr = ptr;
    block->next = garbage_collection;
    garbage_collection = block;
   // printf("Added to garbage collection: %p\n", ptr); // Debug print
}

// Function to free all memory blocks tracked by garbage collection
void garbage_collect() {
    struct MemoryBlock *current = garbage_collection;
    while (current != NULL) {
        struct MemoryBlock *temp = current;
        current = current->next;
       // printf("Freeing: %p\n", temp->ptr); // Debug print
        free(temp->ptr);
        free(temp);
    }
    garbage_collection = NULL;
}

// Function to remove a memory block from the garbage collection list
void remove_from_garbage_collection(void *ptr) {
    struct MemoryBlock *current = garbage_collection;
    struct MemoryBlock *prev = NULL;

    // Traverse the garbage collection list
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (current->ptr == ptr) {
            // Found the memory block to remove
            if (prev != NULL) {
                // Update the previous block's next pointer
                prev->next = current->next;
            } else {
                // If the found block is the head of the list
                garbage_collection = current->next;
            }
           // printf("Removing from garbage collection: %p\n", ptr); // Debug print
            free(current);
            return;
        }
        // Move to the next block
        prev = current;
        current = current->next;
    }

    // If the specified memory block is not found
   // fprintf(stderr, "Error: Memory block not found in garbage collection: %p\n", ptr); // Debug print
}

// Function to get a memory block pointer from the hashtable
void* get_memory_block_pointer(const char *name) {
    unsigned int index = hash(name); // Ensure hash function is accessible

    struct Node *current = hash_table[index]; // Access the hashtable
    while (current != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(current->name, name) == 0) {
            return current->value;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }

    //fprintf(stderr, "Error: Memory block for '%s' not found\n", name);
    return NULL; // Return NULL if not found
}


garbagecollection.h:
// garbage_collection.h

#ifndef GARBAGE_COLLECTION_H
#define GARBAGE_COLLECTION_H

// Define a structure for tracking allocated memory blocks
struct MemoryBlock {
    void *ptr;
    struct MemoryBlock *next;
};

// Function to initialize garbage collection
void initialize_garbage_collection();

// Function to add a memory block to the garbage collection list
void add_to_garbage_collection(void *ptr);

void remove_from_garbage_collection(void *ptr);

void* get_memory_block_pointer(const char *name);

// Function to free all memory blocks tracked by garbage collection
void garbage_collect();

#endif  // GARBAGE_COLLECTION_H


test.hussein:
Import "filen.hslib" 
Import "filto.hslib" 
Void Main(){
testvalue = 40;
Call testvalue;

Var data;
data = ((testvalue/2)/5);
Call data;

};


filen.hslib:
Library{
Var testvalue;
 testvalue = 50;
  Call testvalue; 
};

filto.hslib:
Library{
testvalue = testvalue*2;
Call testvalue;
};

this is quite the project and a probably a lot of bad design decision made by me, but i belive i can fix this issue with a bit of help

Syntax error at what line of code? What token?

@user207421 the syntax error appears in the output (as part of the output of the code), so if i as an example write the input code in the wrong order i get a parse error: syntax error, but in my case i dont have any syntax error in my code, but this appears when i switch from a file to another or from a library file to the main file(input file)

@user207421 should i edit the question, with pictures?
